# Stop an application in bash after a certain amount of time

Tags: command-line, bash, timeout, killall

I am interested in running a bash script which starts an application (in this case VLC), run it for a certain amount of time and then stop it. I can get this application to start just fine, but it will not stop, using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
vlc -vvv http://10.0.0.113:8000/stream.mjpg --sout="#std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=/home/whsrobotics/vlc_project/first_try.mp4}"
sleep 10
killall vlc
```

Not only does it not stop the stream recording, but the app seems to freeze sometimes after I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command to run a command with a time limit. Its basic syntax is:

```
timeout DURATION COMMAND
```

where `DURATION` is a floating point number with the suffix `s` for seconds, `m` for minutes, `h` for hours or `d` for days and `COMMAND` is the command you wish to run.

In your case, you can use:

```
timeout 10s vlc -vvv http://10.0.0.113:8000/stream.mjpg --sout="#std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=/home/whsrobotics/vlc_project/first_try.mp4}"
```

to run your command for 10 seconds and then kill it.

Comment: `timeout 10s` will save the `sleep 10` call and `killall vlc` as well as the need for adding `&` after the command. +1 for that : )

Comment: This one works perfectly!  Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 8):

Add `&` after the second line to put `VLC` in the background like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
vlc -vvv http://10.0.0.113:8000/stream.mjpg --sout="#std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=/home/whsrobotics/vlc_project/first_try.mp4}" &
sleep 10
killall vlc
```

and it will work.

---

**Explaination:**

The shell/terminal will execute commands in the order they are listed in the script and will move to the next command only if the command before it finishes executing.

Which is not the case in your `VLC` command. As long as `VLC` is running, the shell/terminal will consider it still executing and will not move to the command after it but will rather wait for it to finish executing ( ie. in this case closing the `VLC` window/instance ).

A workaround this is to send `VLC` to the background and free the shell/terminal prompt for the next command in the script. Which can be done by adding `&` after the command.

---

**Notice:**

- Remove verbosity option `-vvv` to avoid the script not exiting cleanly and completely.
- If, however, you have to use the verbosity option `-vvv` add `nohup` before the second line as well like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
nohup vlc -vvv http://10.0.0.113:8000/stream.mjpg --sout="#std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=/home/whsrobotics/vlc_project/first_try.mp4}" &
sleep 10
killall vlc
```

This will append output to a file called `nohup.out` in the current working directory if possible or to `~/nohup.out` otherwise and will allow the script to terminate cleanly and completely.

See [man nohup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nohup.1.html) for information.

Best of luck

Comment: killall might be risky though; better to save the pid and kill via that.

Comment: @DanielJour `killall vlc` is not risky as far as system stability is the concern. Plus, that is up to OP to decide. I am just pointing out errors and suggesting fixes. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the most elegant answer (only works with VLC of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
vlc -vvv --stop-time 10 --play-and-exit http://10.0.0.113:8000/stream.mjpg --sout="#std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=/home/whsrobotics/vlc_project/first_try.mp4}"
```

`--stop-time 10` Will stop playback after 10 seconds
`--play-and-exit` Will exit VLC after playback stopped (default is `--no-play-and-exit`)

In some cases you need to use `--run-time` instead of `--stop-time`.

Comment: For some reason the application does not shut down with this approach.

Comment: @SteveC Try to add `--run-time 10` - Apparently that is sometimes needed when dealing with a stream as source.

Comment: You should tell that your answer is specific to vlc and doesn't apply to other use cases.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that this question will be found by people wanting to stop other programs, not just `vlc` on systems that do not have the `timeout` command, so in extension to the already good generic answer by Raffa:

Your attempt would kill all `vlc` processes in the system, not just the one started by this script. Instead you can use the `kill` built-in, as it can accept a bash job specification. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
vlc -vvv http://… &
sleep 10
kill %?vlc
```

The `&` operator in the second line will create a background *bash job*. Then `kill %?vlc` will kill the *bash job* whose prefix is `vlc`.