# Disk space getting used up but clears on reboot

Tags: server, 20.04, disk-usage, tmp

I have a server running ubuntu 20.04

If I run `df`
the first line is:

```
/dev/root       35511052  3512708  31981960  10% /
```

run 2 seconds later i get

```
/dev/root       35511052  3512900  31981768  10% /
```

the problem is after a few weeks the hard drive is full.  If I reboot the system it goes back to about 10% full.  Any ideas what could be eating up my space or how to find it?

I should also mention I have several drives mounted to the system so commands like `sudo du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 20` return the large files on the other drives not the root partition which nothing should be writing to.

**Update 1:**
another question suggested to do the following things:

`sudo du -hsc /tmp`

this returned 56kb and when cleared went down to 4kb and stayed there

`sudo du -hca --time / | grep -E "^[0-9\.]*[G]"`

this returned

```
1.7G    2021-01-04 20:23        /snap
1.6G    2021-01-08 06:19        /usr
```

both times are several hours/days old.  However I will keep monitoring maybe an extra file will show up when the hard drive gets more full.

Another question I found suggested maybe a mount was not actually mounted but I have double checked and mysql, and program working directories are all mounted correctly.

**Update 2:**
ran same tests again from update 1:
`sudo du -hsc /tmp` returns 4K

`sudo du -hca --time / | grep -E "^[0-9\.]*[G]"`

```
1.7G    2021-01-04 20:23        /snap
1.6G    2021-01-08 06:19        /usr
```

Interestingly the / folder in both cases which is made up of multiple drives returns 105GB in both cases but `df` returns the 3GB more then it did yesterday for my root partition.

**Update 3:**
Found a suggestion of using `sudo ncdu -rx /`

Interestingly `df` returns 6.0GiB but `sudo ncdu -rx /` returns 3.2GiB

does this help at all?  I think the problem is related to one app run by crontab is writing a lot to the console.

**Update 4:**
Found the problem.  There is indeed a 2.8GB temp file but it was deleted by the app but not closed so it still took up space.  if I kill the pid the space is cleared.  Any good way to automate killing a process and restarting it on a timer?

**Update 5:**
Service is a crypto wallet run from crontab using it to get chain data.  I did manage to slow the memory leak down considerably but could not stop it.  Also wallet is from an old dead project and code is not buildable anymore or would look in to altering code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 server partition becomes full randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167364/ubuntu-18-04-server-partition-becomes-full-randomly)

Comment: it may.  Will have to let the server run for a day and check.  the temp folder was 56k and the /usr folder showed 1.6G modified today all other folders listed over 1G where not on the same volume.

Comment: I have updated the question because showing responses in comments does not format well.  I will keep monitoring and see if maybe these suggestions help.

Comment: *"Any good way to automate killing a process and restarting it on a timer?"* ... please [edit] and let us know which process and how you run this process. Is it run by a systemd service, a script, crontab or manually? and any extra information to help us give a more accurate solution.

Comment: You cold use `0 * * * *   timeout 3590  nohup YOUR_COMMAND_HERE &` for the cronjob replacing *YOUR_COMMAND_HERE* with the command you use to start your process. This will restart the process every hour waiting 10 seconds for the previous process instance to exit cleanly. Please [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226017/stop-an-application-in-bash-after-a-certain-amount-of-time) for extra info.