# How to schedule close/start a specific program in Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, hibernate

I have a smart mirror that has Linux Ubuntu (Lubuntu) as the operating system
I'm wondering how I can implement the following jobs:

- Every evening at 22.00 //
  1- Close Google chrome.
  2- put the computer into sleep or hibernate mode.
- Every morning at 06.30  //
  1- Wake the computer from sleep or hibernate mode.
  2- Start Google chrome.
  Every Sunday at 22.30 shutdown the computer

Comment: Even though your question title is about starting and stopping a program, the body of the question is about starting and stopping a computer. Does this answer your question? [Automatically sleep and wake-up at specific times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times)

Comment: Also see [this and the linked duplicate question and their answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226017/stop-an-application-in-bash-after-a-certain-amount-of-time) for answers to your question in the title.